# Rollover images used in template stopped working on only one page

Tags: html, dreamweaver, onmouseover, rollover

I have a navigational menu feature on my website, which is part of a template I use on all pages of the site. When you hover over one of the navigational 'buttons' the arrow on the button changes to a blue, downward-facing arrow. All pages are working correctly except for the home page. I've looked through the code, but can't see anything glaring that could be breaking it. Again, the home page is created with the same template used on all the other pages, so this one has me baffled.

Website in question: 'www.rocksolidbullies.com'

This site is designed solely with Adobe Dreamweaver. Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript error in the Facebook code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

This makes the execution of the rollover scripts fail.

I suggest you to go into your FB account and get new code for the Like box.